# ArrayCollection::matching with relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three doctrine2 models:

```
Person
 - $id
 - $schoolClasses (ArrayCollection, OneToMany PersonSchoolClass)

SchoolClass
 - $id

PersonSchoolClass (ManyToOne SchoolClass)
 - $id
 - $schoolClass
 - $person
 - $active
```

In my `Person::addSchoolClass(SchoolClass $schoolClass)`, I want to see, if there is already a `SchoolClass` in my `ArrayCollection<PersonSchoolClass>`.

I use this code:

```
/**
 * @param SchoolClass $schoolClass
 * @return Person
 */
public function addSchoolClass(SchoolClass $schoolClass)
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("schoolClass.id", $schoolClass->getId()))
        ->setFirstResult(0)
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    $t = $this->getSchoolClasses()->matching($criteria);

    if (!$t) {
        $t = new PersonSchoolClass();
        $t->setPerson($this);
        $t->setSchoolClass($schoolClass);
        $this->getSchoolClasses()->add($schoolClass);
    }

    $t->setActive();

    return $this;
}
```

But I always get a timeout at `$this->getSchoolClasses()->matching($criteria);` (process gets killed after a minute or so).

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to check if your `SchoolClass` exists in the collection already before you add it?

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayCollection` has method `contains` which check that entity already on collection.

```
if (!$this->getSchoolClasses()->contains($schoolClass)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, that won't work, because $schoolClasses contains elements of PersonSchoolClass, not SchoolClass.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have already found an answer to your question, but for anyone else that searches for this, ArrayCollection in Doctrine2 can be searched with Criteria, Criteria is a part of Doctrine2 as well and works just like DQL, this page contains all the information needed:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections